# Combine multi-tiered loop into a single query (via plugin)

Tags: plugin-development, queries, query

I am very new to Craft so forgive me if I knacker how this is asked.

I have a set of IDs in an array.  I try sending that into a relatedTo statement (which yields a series of locations...see below code) and from that I loop through those locations, getting some subset descendents of those locations for display.

The issue is, this is a heavy load on the database and without caching takes forever to come back for rendering.   What I would like to do is essentially combine the queries for relatedCampIds, locationCats, and subCategories into a single query that's optimized.  I have tried using the BuildQuery example at https://github.com/tightenco/craft-build-query but I am like a fish out of water and just don't see how I can extend that to do what I'm looking to do.

```
    {# CREATE AN ARRAY OF THE CAMP IDS #}
{% entry = craft.entries.section('pages')}
{% set relatedCampsIds = [] %}
{% set relatedCampsIds = relatedCampsIds|merge(craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf(entry).type('camp').limit(null).ids()) %}

{% set locationCats = craft.categories.relatedTo({ sourceElement: relatedCampsIds }).groupId(1).level(1).order('title').find() %}   

{# get all camps related to the sport/sponsor and Area #}
{% for location in locationCats %}
    {# get all Cities of this Area where there are camps for the given sport/sponsor #}
    {% set subCategories = craft.categories.descendantOf(location).level(2).order('title').relatedTo({ sourceElement: relatedCampsIds}) %}
    {# loop over the subcategories #}
    {% for subCat in subCategories %}
        {# do some display stuff #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Help and understanding are appreciated.